# sobre crud com anexo eu não estou conseguindo fazer a action salvar

Tags: java, groovy, grails

Está adof para fazer funcionar uma actio em Grails.
É o seguinte preciso que a action salve um anexo e um titulo para o anexo.

Alguém me disponibiliza links de cruds com anexos?

Answer (score 1):

Aline,

Infelizmente não posso compartilhar o link, mas coloco os códigos aqui mesmo. Está usando views do Scaffold dinâmico:

Classe marca, omitido o package:

```
class Marca {

  String nome
  byte[] fotografia

  static constraints = {
    nome unique: true
    fotografia nullable: true, maxSize: 1024 * 1024 * 2
  }

}
```

Controller de Marca:

```
class MarcaController {

  static scaffold = true

  static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "DELETE", mostrarFoto: "GET"]

  def mostrarFoto (Marca marcaInstance) {
    if(marcaInstance?.fotografia){
        def byteArray = marcaInstance.fotografia

        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=fotografiaMarca${marcaInstance.id}.jpeg")
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", "${byteArray.length}")
        response.contentType = "application/octet-stream"

        response.outputStream << byteArray
    }
    else{
        '*'{ render status: NO_CONTENT }
    }
  }

  @Transactional
  def save(Marca marcaInstance) {
    if (marcaInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (marcaInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond marcaInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    marcaInstance.save flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'marcaInstance.label', default: 'Marca'), marcaInstance.id])
            redirect marcaInstance
        }
        '*' { respond marcaInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}
```

Qualquer dúvida, poste aqui.

Comment: Oi! O que é isso?  '*'{ render status: NO_CONTENT }

Comment: Aline, com o comando render status: NO_CONTENT, vocÊ está informando para o Grails que é para dar uma resposta com o status NO_CONTENT, cujo código http é o 204. Ou seja, se alguém fizer uma chamada ajax por exemplo, e não existir fotografia para a marca, o Grails retorna esse status para a pessoa. Nessa página (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) você consegue ver os códigos de status do HTTP e seus significados.

Já o comando *{ } significa que é para retornar esse status, independente se foi uma chamada ajax, ou se foi o browser que chamou a action mostrarFoto.